# How do I add Update statement to selected rows I am about to insert into a table with MS SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, sql-delete

I have been busting my head for some time already and without any result.
Honestly I think that I need fresh eyes on this query.
I have written a query that deletes data from one table and puts it into another table. What I can't really figure out, is how to update one column for those rows I am moving, within the same query.
Here is how the query looks:

```
INSERT table1_archive
SELECT * FROM (
    DELETE table
       OUTPUT
            DELETED.*
    WHERE <condition1>
) AS RowsToMove;
```

What I want is to add also

```
UPDATE table1 SET <my_column> = "" WHERE <condition1>
```

Since it is the same condition and table for delete and update, I was thinking that it makes no sense to call two different queries to do some actions for exactly the same rows.
What I want is to clear data out of the <my_column> either before moving rows to table1_archive, or after doing so.

I guess my question is: **How would I apply this update statement to the selected rows I am about to insert into the table1_archive?**

**ANSWER**

This question becomes a little redundant as the UPDATE statement was not necessary to achieve what I wanted. I could just list all my columns in the SELECT statement and replace the <my_column> with NULL, or '''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply manipulate the column to be updated in the select statement.

```
 INSERT INTO table1_archive
 SELECT Col1,Col2...,"" AS <my_column> FROM (
 DELETE table
   OUTPUT
        DELETED.*
 WHERE <condition1>
 ) AS RowsToMove;
```

Comment: What a great little sneaky solution. Thanks. I had this in mind, but it for some reason popped out :D  Is there any specific reason why I have to write "AS <my_column>" in the Select statement, or I can just write down all my columns and replace the <my_column> with null?

Comment: @Oskars, glad its helpful :) . The 'AS <my_column> is for naming your column as <my_column>.If you dont write it,then the column will not have any name.If you want to update NULL as the value for that column,then you have to write NULL AS <my_column>

Comment: more about aliases here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single statement - but it requires that you enumerate the columns.

Assuming that your tables have columns `(col1, col2, col3, mycol)`, where `mycol` should be set to `null` when copied to the archive, you would write this as:

```
with del as (
    delete ...
    output deleted.*
    where ...
)
insert into table1_archive (col1, col2, col3, mycol)
select col1, col2, col3, null
from del
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  table1  SET
    table1.my_column1= table2.my_column1
FROM
       example_table1 AS table1
  INNER JOIN example_table2 AS table2
       ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE
       table1.my_column2 = <condition1>
```

Answer (score 0):

and also you can try this solution

```
UPDATE example_table1 table1 , 
  (SELECT 
    my_column1, my_column2 
  FROM example_table2
  WHERE 
      table1.my_column3=<condition1> 
  ) table2
SET
   table1.my_column1 = table2.my_column1,
   table1.my_column2 = table2.my_column2
 where table1.ID = table2.ID
```